# C# How to retrieve the checkbox value of a setup checkbox dialog?

Tags: c#, installation

In my setup project I have a checkbox dialog after the installation dialog. So when the installation is done a dialog appears with a checkbox on it. In my class I want to access this checkbox. How can I do that?

In the checkbox dialog I have set the Property to CHKRUN. In my class I have overridden the methods:

- OnAfterInstall()
- OnCommitted()
- OnCommitting()

In all the methods I've written the Context.Parameters to a file. The value of the checkbox is always empty. The name of the checkbox (CHKRUN) is visible.

So, how can I retrieve the checkbox value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you set CustomActionData in CustomAction properties window ?
Normally we set something like /chkrun="[CHKRUN]"

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that. Yes I've set that property. Do you know in which method I should access this property(OnAfterInstall, OnCommitted, OnComitting)?

Comment: I'm not sure about your case but I think you can access  Context.Parameters["chkrun"] in your OnAfterInstall method

Comment: I've tried this, but I don't get the value of the checkbox. Do you know other things that I can try?

Comment: Just now I tried and I can't reproduce your problem. I've uploaded my project files to http://cid-7c6ad4aad5dbad7d.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/.Public/TestDeploy.7z . I handle it in OnAfterInstall method and it seems OK. Btw, if you want to debug your application you can put Debugger.Break() in your installer method